# Does laravel cache the config?

Tags: php, laravel, config

Say, I get config with `config('app.configKey')` the first time. Laravel load file app and get the needed key. If I call this the next time, does laravel load the file again? Or it stores the value?

I want to know if I should write:

```
$value = config('app.key');
/* Some code here ... */
$anotherVar = $value;
```

or:

```
$value = config('app.key');
/* Some code here ... */
$anotherVar = config('app.key');
```

It is just an example. In real code I get the config in one class. And later I get this config again in another class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At boot time, Laravel reads all your configuration files and holds their values  in the Application instance. So calling `config('app.configKey')` will not load the the `config/app.php` file, even when calling it the first time.

In your scenario, it really depends what the code behind `/* Some code here ... */` does.

Imagine calling some method, e.g. `$this->changeConfigValue()`, that changes the config value for `app.configKey`. What that actually does is it changes the value in the Application instance, it will not overwrite your config files.

In your first code example, `$anotherVar` would always be equal to `$value`. 
But in the second code example, the value for `$anotherVar` would be read from the App instance again and would be equal to whatever `$this->changeConfigValue()` set the value to.

***This is not a cache.***

Laravel provides a way to cache your config. You can do this manually with an artisan command:

`php artisan config:cache`

This will create the file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` which holds all your configuration in one single file.
When booting, it is faster to read just one file instead of your entire config directory (and that's what a cache is for :P).

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#configuration-caching

Comment: Thanks a lot. But  what I didn't know is only that laravel load all configs at boot time. And I know that it is not real cache, I just used it as 'variables cache'. So if laravel load all configs at the start, I can call `config('app.key')` every time I need this config and not to worry that it slows down the application.